# How to identify unique login user to In app purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

In application there are google In app purchase.User A login in to the application and make purchase.User A sign out from application and User B login in to application.User A and B are different user and that are stored in server. How to identify that the user A has made a purchase.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ObfuscatedAccountId to uniquely identify users. For better understanding refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63298070/8851971).