# Google In App Billing differentiate user accounts

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I'm developing an app that contains In App Billing non consumable product (Life time Subscription).

User has one email associated with Play Store on his device.

Scenario:

User A create new account using user1@test.com and purchase Lifetime Subscription and logout.

User B create new account using user2@test.com and trying to purchase.
 but he get response `BillingClient.BillingResponse.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`.


How do i differ each user to buy item?

I'm using `'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.1'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firebase authentication then you can get user's unique id using `String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` and you can use this Id at the time of purchase like -

```
BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails).setObfuscatedAccountId(uid)
                .build();
        BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);
```

Also in your database use this as unique identifier to check whether user has the subscriotion or not.